# How can i make this generic and make all the available attribute as filtering params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have multiple controllers. and I have a method to filter like this.

```
def filter(filtering_params)
        results = where(nil)
        filtering_params.each do |key, value|
          results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
        end
        results
      end
```

and from controllers, I will call index or show APIs using filtering params for example like this.

```
def filtering_params
        params.slice(:status, :created_at, :id, :transaction_datetime, :portfolio_external_reference_id, :file_id, :file_name)
      end
```

which I will use while fetching from API like this.

```
def index
records = Module::Class.filter(filtering_params)
render json: {
        data: records
      }
end
```

I want to write a generic method that can be used in cases where I want all the available attributes in the particular model as the filtering_params. is there any better way than writing all the attributes?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken if you live in filtering params just `params` instead of `params.slice(:status...` it should return all params

Comment: If I do that, won't it make the service more vulnerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and it's working for me.

```
def filter_params(params)
        values = params.slice(*column_names.map(&:to_sym))
        filter(values)
end
```